# Special Jquery code for submitting a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace the following HTML code

```
<form action="diagrafi.php" method="post" name="users" id="users" onsubmit="return     
check()">
     <input type="submit" name="submit_button" id="submit_button" value="go" />   
</form>
```

with this HTML code

```
<form action="" method="post" name="users" id="users"> </form>
```

and this Jquery code

```
$("#ok").click(function () {
    $("#users").attr("action", "diagrafi.php"); 
    $("#users").submit();
});
```

where "ok" is a button (not submit) outside of form "users" which will replace submit_button. The above code works; however, I cannot find how to embed function check()... 
Please, do not ask why I want this way and do not suggest other solutions. I want exactly what am I asking.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#ok").click(function () {
    if(check()){
        $("#users").attr("action", "diagrafi.php"); 
        $("#users").submit();
    }
});
```

But why do you want it this way? <sub>Sorry, couldn't resist</sub>

you can also chain the 2 methods, so as not to repeat yourself

```
$("#ok").click(function () {
    if(check()){
        $("#users").attr("action", "diagrafi.php").submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since you cannot resist I 'll tell you. I want to confirm with a modal window the form submission. My form has two buttons for two different submission processes. So, I thought the following: each form button (not submit) invokes a modal window.Every modal has a button for a different process, so it could not be submit button; however it has to submit the form. Moreover, only the one of the modals needs the function check().Hope you 've understood... That's all! Is there a better way to implement the above?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want on this way...this will surely work.

```
$("#ok").click(function () {
   $("#users").attr("action", "diagrafi.php");
   $("#users").attr("onsubmit", "return check();");
   $("#users").submit();
});
```

Answer (score -2):

This should work:

```
$("#users").submit(function() {
    if(!check()){
       return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: No, it doesnt. In the OP code a false from `check()` will stop the form submitting. In yours it does nt.

Comment: yes of course... but he just have to do a if(!check()) return false;
i thought that was clear...

Comment: @Jamiec, just curious, what if `event.preventDefault` used in `.submit`

Comment: @Naeem-Shaikh - you can indeed stop the form submitting that way: http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: So twain also has got the solution if preventDefault used.. Is it ?